# Custom 404 error page with same URL

Tags: php, http, error-code

How would one go about enabling a custom 404 page on a 404 request, while retaining the same URL in the address bar instead of it looking something along the lines of `http://yourwebsite.com/error.html`.

Answer (score 3):

Just add the following line to your htaccess file in your root web directory:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404page.html
```

Then make `404page.html` contain whatever text you wish to display to the user.

Comment: No, no, no. I know how to make custom error pages work. What I am asking for is lets say I got to http://yourwebsite.com/poop.html, if that url doesnt exist, I want it to bring up my custom error page but still have http://yourwebsite.com/poop.html in thr URL.

Comment: That code should do that. [Here's an example I did a couple years back.](http://www.idcardonline.com/fart.html)